# Problems linking to social networks in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, social-networking, windows-8-messaging-app, windows-8-people-app

I've upgraded my laptop to Windows 8 (from Windows 7) and I'm having problems with getting information to show in the People and Messaging apps.

I've linked my Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn accounts to my Live Id, and on Windows 7 I was able to see my Friends' facebook activity in Windows Live Messenger.

In the Windows 8 People app I can see all my contacts from Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn, and I can see the on-line status of at least my Facebook contacts.  I can also see the profiles details of each contact, but I don't get anything in the "What's New" view.

The Messaging app is just blank.  I assume I should be able to send messages to my contacts, but I can't see any way to do it.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The Messaging app will be blank when you first use it.  As you begin using it, it will retain your chat history.  To begin a message thread, search for a contact in the **Start a conversation** box:

[image]

The "What's New" view should be populated with your latest updates from your connected accounts.  If you are not seeing any updates, it's possible that there is a network problem, or you aren't signed into your Microsoft account with the linked accounts you should be seeing.  You can ensure that your accounts are connected by looking in the top right corner of the People app:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add accounts to the Messaging app.

Comment: I've added my accounts, and the app says it's successful, but they never appear in the group of icons at the top-right to show the connections.  I've tried with Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install all system and software updates, then open a command prompt (with AR) and enter the following commands:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
net stop dnscache
net start dnscache
```

Restart the computer and see if that worked.